# Determine an inequality

Tags: probability, inequality

I have several inequalities, for instance 
$$
X_1 + X_2 \leq t, X_1 \leq P \text{ and } X_2 \leq P
$$
for random variables $X_1$, $X_2$ and $X_3$. I wonder how I can say about each of the $X_i$?

What I do is to combine the last two inequalities to get $X_1 + X_2 \leq 2P$. So that we have $X_1 + X_2 \leq \min(t, 2P)$. I am wondering if I can say anything about each of the random variable $X_i$. For instance, is it possible to get inequalities like $X_1 \leq A$ and $X_2 \leq B$?

---

Sorry for not mentioning more details. Here in my question, $X_i$'s are all non-negative and $P$ is some given constant. And the the $t$ is just for purpose of illustrating things like $\mathbb{P}\{X \leq t\}$

Comment: Without additional information… no. But if you know e.g. $X_2$ is nonnegative you could conclude $X_1 \leq \min(t, 2P)$ but as mentioned before, this needs additional information.

Comment: I used to think that I can make use of $X_2 \leq P$ (combined with the sum $X_1 + X_2 \leq t$) to get thing like $X_1 \leq \min(t-P, P)$. But this does not seem right. As to yours, I am not sure how to get $X_1 \leq \min(t, 2P)$, because what make sense to me is to add $X_1 \leq P$ to $X_2 \leq P$ and then compare the rest sum $X_1 + X_2 \leq t$

Comment: You are right with $X_1 + X_2 \leq \min(t, 2P)$ but if $X_2$ is nonnegative $X_1$ cannot be greater then $\min(t, 2P)$ because otherwise $X_1 + X_2$ will be as well ($X_2$ is nonnegaitve!). Hence $X_1 \leq \min(t, 2P)$ and also $X_2 \leq \min(t, 2P)$. Btw… you missed some bound for $X_3$?

Comment: Alright, I get what you mean and thanks! My $X_3$ is not important here because it has its own inequality $X_3 > P$

Comment: Your inequalities cut out a convex region to which your random vectors $(X_1,X_2,X_3)$ must be confined.  In  a more complicated problem instance you might, by (say  linear programming)   discover new implied bounds on the $X_i$ individually, of form $a_i\le X_i \le b_i$, maybe.

Comment: Thanks Kimchi! That's what I am working on. For now, the bound on the sum of the random variables still works fine (convolution of distribution functions). But an individual bound would be better.